# Isotope plugin: How to implement 'insertAfter" method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to add an element to the middle of the elements list.

I have tried adding it using jQuery with `insertAfter` method and applying `isotope('reLayout')`.
However, this doesn't really work.

```
  $('#insertAfter a').click(function() {
        var $newEl = $(fakeElement.getGroup()).first();
        $newEl.insertAfter($container.children().eq(3));
        $container.isotope('reLayout');
        return false;
    });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9V2Mj/1/)

Any ideas how to make it work?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isotope does not allow you to manually insert an element into a specific position since it's supposed to automatically handle the element placement. One way to solve your problem is to add a special attribute to every element that can be used to sort the elements in the required order. Then, configure Isotope to use the created attribute to sort the elements. When you need to insert an element, assign a value to that attribute of the new element that will place it into the required position.

Please see the solution on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9V2Mj/20/